# Powershell Pass "Press any key to continue" from another script

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to automate some updates.

For this purpose I need to execute another script and save the output into a variable.

Afterwards I can cut the things that I need off and save them into other variables.

These things theoreticly work but the other script which I'm executing stops the process,
beause it need any key to continue at the end.

Does somebody know how I can pass this?

The scripts stops after:

```
$list = .\list.cmd
```

Kind regards :)

Thats a part of the script:

```
Write-Host "Importing..."
cd "$path"
$list = .\list.cmd

Write-Host "Searching for the certificate file"
$CertificateFile = $list | where {$_ -match "Certificate File:"}
$CertificateFile = $CertificateFile.Substring(18)

Write-Host "I'm trying to find the Password File:"
$PasswordFile = $PasswordFile = $list | where {$_ -match "Password File:"}
$PasswordFile.Substring(15)

Write-Host "Searching for the password file"
$Enddate = $list | where {$_ -match "Validity NotAfter:"}
$Enddate = $Enddate.Substring(19)
```

Comment: Can you post the content of list.cmd?

Comment: just change list.cmd so it doesnt require the key press?

Comment: Can you share what your overarching goal is? Chances are there's a way to do this in PowerShell, without having to call cmd.exe, especially considering you're dealing with X.509 certificate management stuff.

Comment: Hi, 
-The content of list.cmd is just the path to the system certificate & password file and some other infos.
-I can't modify or use the variables from the list.cmd.
-The overall goal is, that some servers in my company need a manual push to update the certificate on them. This can be done by hand, which is a little time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you send a keystroke.  As for timing, it needs to occur when the paused app is in the foreground 'active' window.

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("A")
```

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for your post. I think sending a keystroke after a defined time isn't a solution, is there something like expect in unix? http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect